# Adding a pointer to a sensor to a linked list

Tags: c++, class, pointers, linked-list

I've made a class called "SensorNode", and each SensorNode has a linked list of sensors. One data member of SensorNode is a SensorBlock(the linked list) pointer called mySensors. mySensors points to point to the first sensor in the linked list of sensors owned by the sensor node it's in. Here's the class declaration for SensorNode:

```
class SensorNode {
    char* NodeName;
    int NodeID;
    LOCATION Node1;
    float batt;
    int func;
    SensorBlock *mySensors;


public:
    SensorNode(char *n, float x, float y, float z, int i, float ah);
    void print();
    void setOK(int o);
    int getOK();
    void setLOC(float longi, float lat, float h);
    int amIThisSensorNode(char *n);
    void addSensorToNode(sensor *s);
};
```

and here's the class declaration for SensorBlock:

```
class SensorBlock {

    friend class SensorNode;
    SensorBlock * LLelement;
    sensor * SensEl;
};
```

in the addSensorToNode function, how do I add the pointed to sensor to the linked list.  Basically, what I have is below, and I'm trying to figure out what goes in the "else" statement.  I looked at the tutorials, but they're for creating a new object and adding it, this is for adding a pointer to an object.

```
void SensorNode::addSensorToNode(sensor *s) {
    if(mySensors == '\0')
    {
        mySensors->SensEl = s;
    }
    else{
    //maybe something like this???
       // mySensors->SensEl =s;
       // mySensors->LLelement++;

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Learning data structures with a specific element type in mind seems... unproductive? Is there any thing wrong with  `std::list<sensor*>`?

Comment: It's for an assignment, so I have some limitations, and have to create my own linked list this way.  Also, std::list is a doubly linked list, which may be why for this assignment he wants us to create our own.  Though that's not explicitly stated. I assume it's to learn the concept.  So, conceptually, I'm trying to understand how to add a sensor (via pointer) to the linked list being created.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the skepticism. It does seem like an unusually conflated exercise then. Also, there is `std::slist` and `std::forward_list`, by the way :0

Comment: haha no worries, you're right.  And oh, didn't know about those.  I still can't use them, but good to know for the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimally, a singly-linked list consists of a single pointer to the head node, and each node contains a pointer to the next.

For example:

```
// list -> +-------+   +-------+
//         | next -+-> | next -+-> ...
//         | data  |   | data  |
//         +-------+   +-------+
struct ListNode {
    ListNode *next;
    void *data;
};
typedef ListNode *List;
```

obviously your naming scheme clashes with this, and the data is a `sensor`, but you get the idea.

Now, comparing this with your code, it looks like:

- your `SensorBlock` is really a list node with a weird name,
- your `SensorBlock::SensEl` is the data payload of the node
- your `SensorBlock::LLelement` is the next pointer

If the bizarre naming scheme was your barrier, you should be able to look at any standard text (or wikipedia, or whatever) and see how singly-linked lists work.

So, a standard `push_front` would look something like this:

```
void SensorNode::addSensorToNode(sensor *s) {
    SensorBlock *block = new SensorBlock; // create the new node
    block->SensEl = s;                    // attach its payload
    block->LLelement = mySensors;         // connect it to the list
    mySensors = block;                    // make it the new head
}
```

Note that it deals automatically with a NULL head (you did initialize `mySensors` to NULL in the constructor, right?).

Comment: Thank you!!  I had  SensorBlock newBlock = new SensorBlock();
        newBlock ->SensEl = s;
        newBlock->LLelement = NULL;
        mySensors->LLelement = newBlock;     and kept getting an error, and now I see that the first line needed to be         SensorBlock *newBlock = new SensorBlock;
and you're right, I can get rid of my if statement and make those four line the entire function.  Thanks again!

Comment: one question about that though.  If I set mySensors as the new head then it's no longer pointing to the beginning of the linked list right?  I need to keep mySensors pointing to the beginning of the list so that I can print the list of sensors;

Comment: The beginning of the linked list is whatever you _say_ is the beginning. In this case, the natural order for singly-linked lists is LIFO (last in, first out). This means it behaves as a stack rather than a queue. If you want FIFO ordering, you either get slower (linear-time) insertions or require a tail pointer in addition to the head, and more complex logic.

Answer (score 0):

A plain linked list consists of one anchor and one end pointer, which points to the last element of the linked list.

So you'll need two variables. Here's a possible setup:

```
SensorBlock *Anchor = NULL, *EndPtr = Anchor;
if(!Anchor) EndPtr = Anchor = new SensorBlock(s);  //Assuming that you have a constructor, which takes this parameter.
else EndPtr = EndPtr->LLelement = new SensorBlock(s);
```

This code first checks, whether the anchor is already set or not. If it isn't, the anchor is instantiated and the EndPtr is set to Anchor. Otherwise, it is 'appended' to the list by creating a new SensorBlock element, which is then assigned to 'EndPtr->LLelement' and finally to EndPtr itself.

Be careful to release the dynamically allocated SensorBlock elements once you're done with them and if you delete any element, be sure to update ALL references, which point to it. (Anchor, EndPtr, LLelement of previous element). Otherwise you'll break your chain and destroy the list.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit weird : 
I would have implemented it with a std structure.
If you must implement a custom linked list you may have to change few things.

I would have modified the sensor class as following.

```
class sensor
{
    //members
    //functions

    sensor* next_sensor;
}
```

Then I'd ditch the SensorBlock class.

```
class SensorNode 
{
    private:
        //your members and methods
        sensor *first_sensor;
    public:
        //...
        void addSensorToNode(sensor *s);
};
```

How to add a sensor to the linked list

```
void SensorNode::addSensorToNode(sensor *s) 
{
    sensor* current = first_sensor;
    if(current == NULL)
    {
        first_sensor = s;
    }
    else
    {
        while(current->next_sensor != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next_sensor;
        }
        current->next_sensor = s; 
    }
}
```